# detect how many color shades of a picture inside picture box using vb.net / c#

Tags: .net, picturebox

is there a way to find how many colors present in an image which is loaded to textbox
with out clicking the image,by using some other buttons on the outerside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not quite sure what you are looking for. But yes you can.

[Have a look at this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/Image_Processing_Lab.aspx) The histograms might help you out and the library AForge.NET has a lot of features that could help you.

[As for counting colors this could help](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/159906/Count-Number-of-Unique-Colors-in-an-Image.aspx)